# Add items for dropdown in RNPickerSelect in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-dropdown-picker

i am getting array of objects from api.

The data looks like this.

```
Array [
  Object {
    "code": 230,
    "name": "טרגט",
    "themeColor": "#009fe8",
  },
  Object {
    "code": 270,
    "name": "קוסל",
    "themeColor": "#9c3ab4",
  },
  Object {
    "code": 465,
    "name": "מעיין",
    "themeColor": "#0bb694",
  },
  Object {
    "code": 485,
    "name": "מעיין תיכונים",
    "themeColor": "#009fe8",
  },
  Object {
    "code": 700,
    "name": "משרד החינוך",
    "themeColor": "#9c3ab4",
  },
  Object {
    "code": 701,
    "name": "מ.החינוך אולפני",
    "themeColor": "#0bb694",
  },
  Object {
    "code": 702,
    "name": "חינוך התישבותי",
    "themeColor": "#009fe8",
  },
  Object {
    "code": 984,
    "name": "לא לגעת -חברת הדגמה ",
    "themeColor": "#9c3ab4",
  },
]
```

i want to add a dropdown which contain items as array of objects **"name"** value from
api.

i am using  **RNPickerSelect** from **"react-native-picker-select"**;

```
const [selectedComp, setSelectedComp] = useState("");
  const changeLanguage = (value) => {
    setSelectedComp(value);
  };
<RNPickerSelect
            placeholder={{ label: i18n.t("SET_LANGUAGE") }}
            style={pickerSelectStyles}
            onValueChange={(value) => changeLanguage(value)}
            items={companyName}
            doneText={"בוצע"}
            value={selectedComp}
            useNativeAndroidPickerStyle={false}
            fixAndroidTouchableBug={true}
          />
```

i want the names for the dropdown list coming from array of object list like below one.

```
 טרגט
  קוסל
  מעיין
  מעיין תיכונים
  משרד החינוך
  מ.החינוך אולפני
  חינוך התישבותי
  לא לגעת -חברת הדגמה
```

How can i add **name** from array list for dropdown list?

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [react-native-picker-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-picker-select) documentation, the data you want to display in the dropdown, should have the keyword **label**, but you are trying to display **name** keyword.

> The items for the component to render
>
> - Each item should be in the following format: {label: 'Orange', value: 'orange', key: 'orange', color: 'orange', inputLabel:
>   'Orange!'}
> - label and value are required

Something like this:

```
<RNPickerSelect
      onValueChange={(value) => console.log(value)}
      useNativeAndroidPickerStyle={false}
      placeholder={{ label: "Select your favourite language", value: null }}
      items={[
          { label: "JavaScript", value: "JavaScript" },
          { label: "TypeStript", value: "TypeStript" },
          { label: "Python", value: "Python" },
          { label: "Java", value: "Java" },
          { label: "C++", value: "C++" },
          { label: "C", value: "C" },
      ]}
  />
```

Comment: i want the "name" value from array of objects in the items of RNPickerSelect.

Comment: not keyword "name"...i want just value of "name" attribute from array of objects.

Comment: According to the docs, RnPickerSelect won't be able to auto detect name, you need to change the keyword name to label like  **{ {
    "code": 700,
    "label": "משרד החינוך", 
   "value": "משרד החינוך",
  }}**